# Can't get word-spacing CSS property to work correctly

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I was trying to start in this wonderful world of programming due to my quarantined country (Mexico to be exact), and then I faced a problem that I could not fix no matter what I did, this part of the code did not work:

HTML:

```
<p class="property_5">  
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Nulla pellentesque metus eget massa feugiat lobortis.
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.property_1 {
    word-spacing: normal;
}

.property_2 {
    word-spacing: nowrap;
}

.property_3 {
    word-spacing: pre;
}

.property_4 {
    word-spacing: pre-wrap;
}

.property_5 {
    word-spacing: pre-line;
}
```

I putted the other code because I switch among every single property and It did not work either when I changed the declared class on the `<p>` on the index.

I´m using Chrome and I already tried:

- Delete the cache (and nothing happened)
- Don't put the text inside of a box
- Delete every text-align referred to the paragraphs (and the whole website, I used to had everything on the html tag `center`)
- Change among three browsers (and nothing happened either)
- Delete every single `<BR>` on the text (and the same with another bigger text than this one)

Please I need your help, I even forgot to include the CSS file on the HTML but this is out of my control.

Comment: Welcome to programming :). Yeah, this world requires a lot of patience and attention to detail. Very small differences can be essential to working code. It takes practice together good at those things, but you can get it :). You did do the right thing by experimenting before asking questions, so thanks for that! One thing that might help you a lot is learning the [web inspector tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css) of your browser. They can often tell you what is wrong if you use them correctly.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner This is not programming. This is structure and styling only.

Comment: @Rob The skills needed are close enough :). You know what I mean :).

Comment: In fact, I already know how to handle some c++ (and I am starting with the book "c++ primer"), but you know, I refer to everything with code programing for comfortability (besides thanks for the fact, I didn't know that the css with html is not actual programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing `word-spacing` with `white-space`.
The values you are setting refer to the `withe-space` property.

Here are some references:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: With your comment I noticed about something weird, in the comments that I write before for don't forget the syntax (because I learn better acting as if I were doing things for teach to other people) I wrote "white-space property" not "word-spacing property" which It's very interesting now that I analyzing better the situation because before of that code I putted the syntax of the word-spacing property XDDD. In conclusion, I need to see more on the details and thanks for your attention <3

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.property_5 {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why this works and the given examples don't?

Comment: he was using word-spacing which is used for space between words and his problem is with white-space which is used for white spacing (empty text or extra space).

Comment: Though your answer might solve the question in hand, it's not very valuable to the community without an explanation of why this is the right answer. Consider improving your answer by descrbing why you think this is the right answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer